# Dyadic daily diary analysis

Tags: multi-level, structural-equation-model

I have this daily diary dataset measured among couples. So it has two levels: individual-level and couple-level.

X was measured in the **evening** from **Monday** to Friday.

M was measured in the **morning** from **Tuesday** to Saturday.

Y was measured in the **evening** from **Monday** to Friday.

Therefore, all variables were assessed 5 times but X and Y assessed at the same time.

My bosses wanted me to build this mediation model: X (a previous evening assessment)--> M (the next morning assessment)-->Y (the next evening assessment).

What I came up with is a cross-lagged panel mediation (see figure) which means (if my understanding is right) for X, we can only use the first 4 days'data and for M and Y, we can only use the last four days' data because X and Y were assessed at the same time. My boss felt there should be a way to use data of all five days for each variable.

Are there other ways of analyzing this utilizing data of all five days for each variable? Or what are the proper ways of testing this mediation model? Thanks so much!

(The Figure was copied and pasted from Selig & Preacher, 2009)
([image: Figure])